# Access or modify instance variable within AsyncTask

Tags: android, thread-safety, android-asynctask

Suppose I have a innerclass extends asynctask called A and the outerclass extends Activity B.
Is it thread-safe that the code in A access or modify the instance variable in Activity B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [an AsyncTask runs in a separate thread](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask) so you'll have to do the usual thread synchronization if the Activity and AsyncTask share state (in this case instance variables) while the AsyncTask is running.

Generally, to make it easy, you implement [`onPublishProgress()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...)) and [`onPostExecute()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)) to publish state from the AsyncTask to the Activity, since both methods are posted to run in the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

If you access the instance directly without `synchronize`, then no, the code is **not** thread safe.
You have to use `synchronize` for that or just simply access the instance from `onPublishProggress()` method of `AsyncTask`.